# how to reuse StringBuilder in a loop?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

*What am trying to do here is to improve speed performance by using StringBuilder outside the loop and clear StringBuilder in each cycle for reuse* , but seems like this approach doesn't always work , because I didn't see improvement in speed performance.*

```
public class Loader implements Runnable {
    private int i;

    public Loader(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("res/NUMBERS " + i + ".txt");
            char letters[] = {'У', 'К', 'Е', 'Н', 'Х', 'В', 'А', 
                              'Р', 'О', 'С', 'М', 'Т'};
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            
            for (int regionCode = 1; regionCode <= 199; regionCode++) {
                stringBuilder.setLength(0);
                for (int number = 1; number < 1000; number++) {
                    for (char firstLetter : letters) {
                        for (char secondLetter : letters) {
                            for (char thirdLetter : letters) {
                                stringBuilder.append(firstLetter)
                                        .append(padNumber(number, 3))
                                        .append(secondLetter)
                                        .append(thirdLetter)
                                        .append(padNumber(regionCode, 2))
                                        .append("\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                writer.write(stringBuilder.toString());
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String padNumber(int number, int numberLength) {
        String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
        int padSize = numberLength - numberStr.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < padSize; i++) {
            numberStr = '0' + numberStr;
        }
        return numberStr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            new Thread(new Loader(i)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

When I used the StringBuilder inside the loop it took 30 sec for the process to finish, but with this approach shown above is taking 50 sec for the process to finish which was not what I expected.Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the StringBuilder API for the default constructor: `Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial capacity of 16 characters.`, So I would guess that when you reset the length the capacity is also changed. You can verify this by using the `capacity()` method after setting the length. If the capacity is set to 0, then I guess more processing is required to allocate internal buffers as you add characters. Maybe try using the `ensureCapacity(...)` method to set a size to minimize the creation of internal buffers.

Comment: Taking out the file writing and multiple threads/loops - I found that the "core" work takes about 14s using your current code.  I tried optimising the padding workflow using `StringBuilder` and that sucked.  I tried using `String.format` and the sucked even more.  I tried using `stringBuilder.delete(0, stringBuilder.length() - 1);` instead of `stringBuilder.setLength(0);` and that was marginally worse.  About the only advice I can give right now is to seed the `StringBuffer` with a reasonable large size - I used `1024` as a starting point, as well as using `BufferedWriter`

Comment: I did a another really quick test and found the length of you content is `15536448` - so you should seed the `StringBuilder` with that - this will prevent it from having to resize the buffer, at least on the initial pass ‍♂️. This might shave a few milliseconds

Comment: You are focusing on optimizing StringBuilder when in fact your implementation of `padNumber` is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the performance:

1. Using [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs//api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) can improve the performance by reducing the number of I/O operations.

```java
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out/NUMBERS-" + i + ".txt"));
```

2. Using Java's [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or other parallel processing techniques. This involves dividing the workload among multiple threads to take advantage of the processors.

You would specify an executor service backed by a pool of a certain number of threads. Adjust the number of threads based on your goal and your number of CPU cores. Submit your tasks defined as `Runnable` or `Callable` objects.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
```

I tried this and it took **20 seconds** (See the foto below)

[image]

In Java 21+, using [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) is generally best for tasks that involve blocking such as file I/O.

An `ExecutorService` is `AutoCloseable`. So we can use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close and shutdown when done.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int limit = … ;
    try(
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
    ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            executorService.execute(new Loader(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated your example to take advantage of (a) the fact that `ExecutorService` is now `AutoCloseable`, and (b) virtual threads.

Comment: I was also advised to reduce the calls of method padNumber which can help in improving the speed performance , but I find it somehow difficult to figure this out.

Comment: In my opinion you can also leave it like that because functions use the stack which is a memory area so the profermance you don't notice it easily.

Answer (score 0):

`setLength` is more time intensive than the StringBuilder's constructor. Granted, you won't see a difference until you start measuring at the  nanosecond level, but the idea that you will save time by reusing the same instance of a StringBuilder is faulty.

Something like this would be a great candidate for concurrency if your focus is simple speeding up the process.

Comment: do you have some backup information/test of `setLength` being more time intensive? I cannot really find how that is the case in the source code. Additionally do not forget GC work needed to delete old instances of the `StringBuilder` when a new is created